# Best HID device communication libary C++

Tags: c++, protocols, hid

I want to send bytes to a HID device.
I've allready tried [libhid](https://github.com/bfoz/libhid) but I can't get it to work.
Does anyone know a libary or a easy way to send bytes via. HID in C++.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [hidapi](https://github.com/libusb/hidapi) lib.

Also will be usefull for you [same question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/280199/10504918).